# Compare an item in a list to a string and then remove another item

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to compare an item in a list to a string using the item's index.  However, the code is not doing what it is meant to do.  It is supposed to remove another item in the list.

Here is the code:

```
If (result.Count = 12) Then
    If (result.item(2) = "US") Then
        result.Remove(7)
    End If
    TextBox8.Text = result(11)
Else
    result.Remove(11)
    TextBox8.Text = ""
End If
```

Based on the results the index (2) has the word "US" but for some reason it is not working and not removing the other item.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code?  Because somewhere, your assumption is wrong.  Are you sure it is `"US"` and not `"US "`, for example?  Or is the case different?  Ultimately we wont' be able to solve this problem without seeing the actual value of `result`, so the question as it stands is unanswerable except to say "Check again..."

Comment: @Dan Puzey I debugged and founf that Index no. (2) in the list `result` has `"US"`. so what would be the problem?

Comment: When you step through your code, does it enter the `if` statement and step over the line `result.Remove(7)`?  Further, is the type of `Result` a `List`?  Because if it is, I suspect you mean `result.RemoveAt(7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Puzey pointed out, the `Remove` method removes the given object from the list.  So, when you call `Remove(7)`, it does not remove the seventh item from the list, but rather, it removes the number seven, itself, from the list.  I suspect what you are actually trying to do is to remove the seventh element (whatever object that happens to be), in which case you want to instead call `RemoveAt(7)`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code.
So you have an error:

TextBox8.Text = result(11) 'Index was out of range

It is logical since you had 12 items (index from 0 to 11). You remove index number 7.
So now you have 11 items (index 0 to 10). You cannot get the value from 11.
The actual remove is working perfect. What is your problem?
The second part of the if:

```
    Else
        result.Remove(11)
        TextBox8.Text = ""
    End If
```

works only if result.count <>12 
Which also has problem because if result.Count =5 you cannot remove(11).
Maybe it is better to tell as what you want to achieve.

***PS. I imagined that your list is something like that:

```
    Dim result As New List(Of String)
    For i = 0 To 11
        result.Insert(i, i.ToString)
    Next
    result(2) = "US"
```